# I used third party library for slider image, but for offline mode images are displayed in image sliderview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-imageview

I used third party library for sliding images, but for offline storage i used SQLite  whole JSON data sent into SQLite.IF  sqlite there is only image url when internet is not available that time images cannot be display in imageslider, but all images are displayed in imageslider.i don't know  only url
    in SQLite how it is possible to show in imagesliderview.

I don't want to display when offline mode in android.

I used this library compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.0.3@aar'

This is offline mode code for sliderimages:

```
private void BannerImageOffline() {

    String BannerImages = db.getNumbers(Constants.BannerImages);


    Log.d(TAG, BannerImages.toString());
    if (BannerImages != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject bannerimages=new JSONObject(BannerImages);
            //   int status=jsonObject.optInt("status");

            String status = bannerimages.optString("status");
            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("200")) {//check the status 200 or not
                try {
                    bannerpath = bannerimages.getString("bannerPath");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                try {
                    JSONObject response = bannerimages.getJSONObject("response");
                    jsonArray = response.getJSONArray(DATA);


                    if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                        // looping through json and adding to movies list
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            try {
                                JSONObject alertObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                                String images = bannerpath + alertObj.getString("banner_name");
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                map.put(FLAG, images);
                                for (String name : map.keySet()) {
                                    // TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(MainActivity.this);
                                    DefaultSliderView textSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(getActivity());
                                    // initialize a SliderLayout
                                    textSliderView
                                            // .description(name)
                                            .image(map.get(name))
                                            .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                                            .setOnSliderClickListener(Home_Page.this);

                                    //add your extra information
                                    textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
                                    textSliderView.getBundle()
                                            .putString("extra", name);

                                    mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }


                        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // stopping swipe refresh
                // swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                hidepDialog();
            } // condtion check the status 200
            else // this is if status falied in runtime
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Status Failed in Banner Page check ur network connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
                }

        catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

                    // If  condtion end of the project

                }

}
```

Anyone solve this problem Glad to appreciate.

Comment: So .. did you find a solution?

Comment: No,I didn't found but still offline mode image are displaying in image slider,i think that third party has cache like this think so

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,  you want to display all the images if connected and ... if not connected,  only the images that have more than just the url right?

The best way to do this,  in my opinion, would be to handle it on the SQL side.

For example:

```
getResults (boolean isConnected) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM tableName";
        if (!connected)
            query += " WHERE someOtherFieldThanUrl IS NOT NULL";
//query the request
}
```